# SQL : creating a new column name - converting query from MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, view

Here's the MS Access query of a new column name - SonucMF:

`IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF]);IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]);[Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET];[KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]);[KampanyaDetayTbl]![KMMF])`

I'm trying to convert this query to MS SQL view:

`IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF],0),IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF],0),[Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET],[KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF]),[KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF])`

I'm getting "Invalid or missing expression" error.

Edit : Here's the complete query ;

```
 SELECT 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    DepolarTbl.[Müşteri Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD, Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[DEPO ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE GLN KODU], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] AS [Ürün Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[SATIŞ ADET], 
    IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF]), IIf(IsNull([KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]), [Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET], [KampanyaDetayTbl]![BMMF]),[KampanyaDetayTbl]![KMMF]) AS SonucMF, 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[MF ADET] AS [Istenen MF], 
    IIf([SonucMF]=[Istenen MF],"Yok","Var") AS Duzenleme, 
    [Fiyat] * ([Istenen MF] - [SonucMF]) AS Tutar
FROM 
    ((Birlesmis_Data_Urun 
LEFT JOIN 
    KampanyaDetayTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.ID = KampanyaDetayTbl.MFID)  
INNER JOIN 
    DepolarTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD = DepolarTbl.KOD) 
LEFT JOIN 
    UrunFiyatTbl ON (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.UrunAdi) AND (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.KampanyaAdi);
```

Comment: Show us the complete query.

Comment: added complete Ms Access query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see three problems:

- exclamation marks (these don't work in SQL Server like in Access; use a dot to separate table name and column name)
- quotation marks - it's better practice to use single quotes
- IsNull(x) function - in SQL Server, use just x IS NULL

Try:

```
 SELECT 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    DepolarTbl.[Müşteri Adı], DepolarTbl.[BM Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD, Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[DEPO ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE GLN KODU], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[ECZANE ADI], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] AS [Ürün Adı], 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[SATIŞ ADET], 
    IIf([KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF] is null, IIf([KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF] is null, [Birlesmis_Data_Urun].[MF ADET], [KampanyaDetayTbl].[BMMF]),[KampanyaDetayTbl].[KMMF]) AS SonucMF, 
    Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[MF ADET] AS [Istenen MF], 
    IIf([SonucMF]=[Istenen MF],'Yok','Var') AS Duzenleme, 
    [Fiyat] * ([Istenen MF] - [SonucMF]) AS Tutar
FROM 
    ((Birlesmis_Data_Urun 
LEFT JOIN 
    KampanyaDetayTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.ID = KampanyaDetayTbl.MFID)  
INNER JOIN 
    DepolarTbl ON Birlesmis_Data_Urun.KOD = DepolarTbl.KOD) 
LEFT JOIN 
    UrunFiyatTbl ON (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Düzeltilmiş Ürün Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.UrunAdi) AND (Birlesmis_Data_Urun.[Kampanya Adı] = UrunFiyatTbl.KampanyaAdi);
```

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '('.

Comment: Nested `IIf( ... IS NULL)` become much more readable with `COALESCE`.

Comment: No problem, and also take a look at what @Andre suggested, because your IIF would look much better as COALESCE :) good luck~~

Comment: Thanks marmarta  and Andre  you're awesome :)